How can i create an interface that contain all imported classes from a folder
i have a folder containing many class that all extend same class.
i want to create a dynamic interface that contain a key for each imported class and the value type if the class.
for example:
//dummy1.ts
export class Dummy1 {}

//dummy2.ts
export class Dummy2 {}

//index.ts
import {Dummy1} from './dummy1';
import {Dummy2} from './dummy2';

/////// This interface should be auto generated as below
export interface AllDummies {
  dummy1: Dummy1;
  dummy2: Dummy2;
}

i try to use keyof, typeof or any other things i found on the network without success.
i try to define arrays of key, value pairs without success.
const names = ['dummy1', 'dummy2'] as const;
const types = [Dummy1, Dummy2] as const;

but then didn't know how to define the interface with different type to each key
export type AllDummies = {
    [K in typeof names[number]]: ?????types[K];
}

i also try to use the export type option so i could import all keys.
export { Dummy1 as dummy1 } from './dummy1';
export { Dummy2 as dummy2 } from './dummy2';

and then in the upper import define a dynamic type. but i was unable to create an instance of it becuase all types was defined as typeof XXX
type AllDummies = { [d in keyof typeof Dummies]: typeof Dummies[d] };

